# Importar ficheiros CSV MySql

Tags: mysql, xampp

Estou a usar o Xampp como servidor e o MySqlWorkbench como base de dados, como é que consigo fazer importação de um ficheiro csv para fazer varias experiências (tamanho do ficheiro, tempo de upload,etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem muitas formas de você fazer isso, mas independente de qualquer forma adotada, primeiro você tera que criar a tabela com a determinada estrutura (colunas e campos) para que você popular ela com o arquivo CSV ou qualquer outro que você queira importar.

Acho que este tutorial pode lhe ajudar [Importando cvs para o mysql](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/)

O MySQL possui um comando para importar um arquivo CSV diretamente em uma tabela (e parece ser bem rápido).

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'arquivo' INTO TABLE 'tabela'
```

[Mais um tutorial em Português](http://www.vidageek.net/2013/02/27/importar-csv-mysql/)

Comment: paulo roberto obrigado, e como testo por exemplo na importação quantos Gb o .csv pode conter?

Comment: @Rodrigo não há limitação de tamanho...Uma vez que você não determinou isso no script, ele ira importar exatamente tudo que houver na planilha.

Comment: então basicamente senao existe restricoes no tamanho e se tiver um ficheiro mais pesado demora mais tempo a processar e vice-versa? Então quais são os pros/contras desse da importação desse tipo de ficheiros (que possam ser testadas)?

Comment: @Rodrigo isso é bom para quando você ja tem uma planilha com muitíssimas informações e não quer correr o risco de perdê-las, ai você importa elas para o banco e usa somente as colunas que realmente for precisar, porém tendo as outras informações não tão uteis guardadas juntinhas no banco. Não vejo nenhum ponto negativo a não ser a demora no processamento caso a planilha seja muito longa, mas isso não é impeditivo para os micros de hoje em dia...Você pode testar N condições, como se ele importara informações duplicadas caos você mande importar de novo, se corrompe devido o tamanho do csv e etc.

Comment: exatamente no que referiu se corrompe devido ao tamanho do csv quer dizer o que então que é limitado a tamanho? É essa parte que não estou a entender

Comment: @Rodrigo Eu estou lhe passando esta condição para que você teste se Ele corrompera se você pegar um arquivo grande, não sera uma limitação do banco caso isso corra, sera uma limitação da capacidade de processamento do seu micro...Leia um pouco sobre importação de CSV e você vera que tem muitas circunstancias a serem testadas, ja que seu objetivo é aprender...Va colocando suas duvidas no site, que nós vamos respondendo na medida do possivel. Não esqueça de votar como resposta.

Comment: muito obrigado acho que ja entendi!

Comment: ao tentar importar um ficheiro csv do pc da me este erro: error calling Python module function o que sera?

Comment: @Rodrigo abra uma nova pergunta para este erro, por favor.